# How to get WifiConfiguration creator?

Tags: android

I use Wifimanager addNetwork() add three configurations, then I want to delete these.

how to get the configuration that my app creates.

Answer (score 0):

If I got you right, you need to remove these added WiFis from your app.

use `removeNetwork(int networkID)` of `WiFiManager` class

```
List<WifiConfiguration> list = wifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks();
for( WifiConfiguration i : list ) {
    wifiManager.removeNetwork(i.networkId);
}
```